# mysql query to fetch only hex ascii data?

Tags: mysql, regex, hex, ascii

I need a MySQL query to get the below expected output processing the above input data??(in my data i get junk data ranging from \x128 to \x160(Hex data) ASCII characters.).so,I need a regex pattern to fetch only the data that contains hex values and remaining all the values to be NULL except the key column Name.

```
   Input data :
      **NAME    PHONE   ADDRESS**
        anu     345@2   hyderabad
        vinu    1234    raj^am
        ram      234    vizag
        kheer   233&3   vz1m
        palni   1333    rap#d


    Required output data:
       **NAME   PHONE   ADDRESS**
        anu     345@2   NULL
        vinu    NULL    raj^am
        kheer   233&3   NULL
        plain   NULL    rap#d
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use 2 query for this result first on PHONE column and 2nd is ADDRESS Column
1.UPDATE test1 SET Phone=NULL WHERE Phone REGEXP '[@^]'
2.UPDATE test1 SET Address=NULL WHERE Address REGEXP '[@^]'

Answer (score 0):

```
HEX(phone) REGEXP '^(..)*[89ABCDEF]'
```

will match any phone with any non-Ascii bytes.

I suspect you did not mean x128, nor x160.  Those numbers look more like decimal.  If you want to catch >= 128 and < 160 (note: not <= 160):

```
HEX(phone) REGEXP '^(..)*[89]'
```

The REGEXP says:

```
^ -- anchored at start
(..)* -- skip any number of pairs of characters (remember they are hex)
[89] -- match 8x or 9x
-- ignore the rest of the column
```